# S3FS not recognizing AWS ID and secret as environment variables

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos, s3fs

Using S3FS v1.83 (and v1.84), I source environment variables from a file in a script I've written to use the s3fs command. Unfortunately S3FS does not see the AWS key and secret environment variables even though they're in the environment. I'm using CentOS 7.5 with the latest package updates.

Passing them in as variables on the command line works, exporting them works too, but not sourcing a file.

```
BUCKET_NAME=[bucketname]
MOUNT_LOCATION=[mountlocation]
AWSACCESSKEYID=XXXXXXXXXX
AWSSECRETACCESSKEY=XXXXXXXXX
```

After sourcing the file, in my script I just call s3fs with the bucket name and mount location. Here is a snippet of the script:

```
CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION=/root/.aws_backup_config
if [ -a $CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION ]; then
   source $CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION
else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   echo "AWS Backup configuration does not exist at
$CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION"                                                                                                                                                              
   exit 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
fi                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
echo "Mounting S3 bucket at $MOUNT_LOCATION"                                                                                                                                                                                                 
echo $AWSACCESSKEYID
echo $AWSSECRETACCESSKEY

#Mount the S3 Bucket at MOUNT_LOCATION
s3fs $BUCKET_NAME $MOUNT_LOCATION
S3FS_RC=$?                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
if [ $S3FS_RC != 0 ]; then
     echo "Failed to mount bucket! Something isn't configured correctly! Check server messages log."
```

What seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

s3fs does support `AWSACCESSKEYID` and `AWSSECRETACCESSKEY` credentials but [a regression](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/864) prevented its use.  1.85 will include [a fix](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/pull/877) for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

s3fs does not uses ENV to recognize credentials.
They should be stored in :

echo ACCESS_KEY_ID:SECRET_ACCESS_KEY > ${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs

chmod 600 ${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs

Comment: I'm using that as a workaround but according to the source code here: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/blob/master/src/s3fs.cpp#L4176 it should be grabbing it from the environment.

Comment: According to the link you gave s3fs trying to get credentials from : AWSACCESSKEYID and AWSSECRETACCESSKEY.   All AWS services (cli, boto3 working with AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY). As i see s3fs defines it's own env vars, deifferent from AWS related tools.

Comment: Which goes back to my original question, when I spceify AWSSECRETKEYID and AWSSECRETACCESSKEY as environment variables by sourcing a file in the script, why can't s3fs see that?

Comment: File structure is AWSSECRETKEYID:AWSSECRETACCESSKEY, sourcing file will not export any env vars.       export AWSSECRETKEYID=$(cat ~/.passwd-s3fs | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[1]}'), same story for the second variable, AWSSECRETACCESSKEY (change to '...print [2]')

Comment: Seems like an obsolete answer @yuriypolonskiy, why not delete it in favor of developers answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54102514/9962007?